# login to google cloud in swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-compute-engine

I have a linux vm instance in the google cloud compute engine.

I need to make an ios application in which I connect to my google cloud virtual instance and run a couple of scripts. I already have this application on my Android phone and have the private key on the phone for testing purposes so I can connect to google cloud and do what I wrote. My question is:

Which would be easiest way (I only want to test the app on my own phone for now) to connect to the virtual instance on the google cloud and run the scripts?

- Firebase
- NSTask:

  ```
  @IBAction func btnClicked(sender: NSMenuItem) {
  let task = NSTask()
  task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/"
  if (sender.state == NSOnState) {
      sender.state = NSOffState
      task.arguments = ["dotte@11*.13.42.21*", "ls"] }}
  ```
- or a better way

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will want to be more precise in exactly what you are using. Do you mean Compute Engine? Something else? Definitely doesn't seem right to have tagged this App Engine.

Comment: Yes, I have a linux vm instance in compute engine on which I'd like to run a couple of scritpts. Do you have any good idea to do that? Thanks